# Segue is not passing a value from my StoriesTableViewController to SingleArtCallViewController. Why could this be?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

If a user clicks on the table-item in my StoriesTableViewController, I need to pass the value of the id to the SingleArtCallViewController so that the SingleArtCallViewController can display the appropriate details.

Thing is, if I print the id of the item that the user has pressed on, it is correctly printing it. But it's not being received in the other ViewController. Can someone solve this problem for me?

StoriesTableViewController:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    myIndex = indexPath.row

    finalId = idTable[myIndex]

    let story = stories[indexPath.row]
    ArtcallID = story.id


   performSegue(withIdentifier: "singleArtcall", sender: self)
}

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


print(ArtcallID + "is the index of the item that was selected")
   //this correctly prints the id
let id = segue.destination as! SingleArtcallViewController
    id.ArtcallID = ArtcallID
 //  print("id: ",id)

   }
```

SingleArtCallViewController:

```
var ArtcallID: String!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        print("ArtcallID: ", ArtcallID)

        //If I print this I"m getting the result "ArtcallID:  some("")"


    }
```

Story.swift:

```
import Firebase

class Story
{
    var id: String = ""
    var text: String = ""
    var numberOfLikes = 0
    var numberOfAngry = 0
    let ref: DatabaseReference!
    var fundedAmt: Int = 0
    var targetAmt: Int = 0
    var perfCity: String = ""
    var targetDate: IntMax = 0
    var backers: Int = 0
    var fundedPercent: Int = 0
    var imageURL: String = ""

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Fund").childByAutoId()
    }

    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
    {
        ref = snapshot.ref
        if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            text = value["artist_name"] as! String
            backers = value["total_backers"] as! Int
            perfCity = value["perf_location"] as! String
            fundedAmt = value["amount_funded"] as! Int
            targetAmt = value["target_amount"] as! Int
            fundedPercent = value["percent_funded"] as! Int

          //  numberOfLikes = value["numberOfLikes"] as! Int
          //  numberOfAngry = value["numberOfAngry"] as! Int
            id = snapshot.key
        }
    }
```

Comment: SingleArtCallViewController or SingleArtcallViewController which one is right ?

Comment: SinlgeArtCallViewController is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, and you created the segue by control dragging from prototype cell to SingleArtcallViewController:

The specific reason why code doesn't work is that prepare(for segue:...) runs earlier than tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath). More over you run prepare for segue twice.

If so, You don't need the method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Just use prepare(for segue:...):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row,
        let vc = segue.destination as? SingleArtcallViewController else {return}
    vc.artCallId = stories[selectedRow].id
}
```

Comment: Worked like a dream! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, are your: `story.id` a string ?

Have you tried to pass another test value? If so, it works?

Comment: But to answer your question, if I pass the String 'hello', that gets transmitted!

Comment: Let me upload my Story.swift file.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

   if segue.identifier == "singleArtcall"{
        let id = segue.destination as! SingleArtCallViewController
        id.getID = ArtcallID
       }
}
```

---

```
var getID: String?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("ArtcallID: ", getID)
    }
```

Comment: try to add a print in prepare after the if condition, what it is printing ?

Comment: So I added the following print statement after if:
    print(getID + " is the value of the getID. Value of the ARtcallID is: " + ArtcallID)
My output:
is the value of the getID. Value of the ARtcallID is: -asdffdsa123

Comment: That means the ArtcallID is correctly getting recorded but the string getID is not assuming its value. I don't know why.